# Using the VMware SDK, Java, vCenter how do you get all the Networks attached to a VM?

Tags: sdk, vmware

I get the VM object and do a retrieve of the Networks but I only get one. Event if the 
VM has several NICS on different networks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API reference](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50/vim.VirtualMachine.html), the 'network' property on the VirtualMachine managed object should get you what you want. I've used this property before, and I believe it works just fine.

What call are you making, and what results do you get? An example would help debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but if it helps....

You can do it easily with PowerCli:

```
PS > connect-viserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Port 443  -User xxx -Password xxx
PS > Get-NetworkAdapter -VM  xxx.xxx.com

Name                 Type       NetworkName  MacAddress         WakeOnLan
                                                                 Enabled
----                 ----       -----------  ----------         ---------
Network adapter 1    e1000      xxx          xx:yy:zz:ad:46:46       True
Network adapter 2    e1000      xxx          xx:yy:zz:ad:46:4b       True
```